# Python: list comprehension - faster alternative?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists:

1. List of words `allwords` (~100.000 elements)
2. List of stopwords `stopwords` (~2.000 elements)

I want to generate a new list `selectedwords` from list `allwords` with all words that are not in `stopwords`.

I achieved this via the below list comprehension

```
selectedwords = [word.lower() for word in allwords  if word.lower() not in stopwords]
```

**Question:** is there a smarter way to do this that speeds up the calculation (using python). I am rather new to python and am grateful for any advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Calling `word.lower()` twice doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `stopwords` a `set`, then the `not in` check is fast.

Edit: Some benchmark comparing it with @deceze's way (I removed the `.lower()` and the preparation of the stop words set (it's small anyway) in order to focus on the actual difference of the two ways).

```
from timeit import timeit

allwords = list(map(str, range(100000)))
stopwords = list(map(str, range(0, 100000, 50)))

stopwords_set = set(stopwords)

for _ in range(3):
    print(timeit(lambda: [word for word in allwords if word not in stopwords_set], number=100),
          timeit(lambda: set(allwords) - stopwords_set, number=100))
```

Output (three rounds, left time is list comprehension, right time is set difference):

```
0.5209118997490783 0.9618692664857642
0.5104636869544419 0.9020013947776662
0.48269282831284466 0.8888132040554915
```

So in this test the list comprehension was consistently and significantly faster than the set difference.

And for comparison, a test with a stopwords *list*:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: [word for word in allwords if word not in stopwords], number=100)
271.4802689439021
```

Comment: Make *both* lists a `set` and get the difference…

Comment: @deceze That would lose the order and duplicates and thus not achieve the same thing.

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be duplicates present, and OP didn't specify order as being relevant, but, okay, that *might* be a reason.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. This speeds up the process significantly and still keeps duplicates in list of allwords (which I need but which I did not specify indeed). Why is using set so much faster?

Comment: @FredMaster The basic idea is that `set` creates an index, it's like turning a list of words into an ordered paper dictionary.

Comment: @FredMaster It's a hash set (see [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)). Instead of searching a word in a list from front to back, it somewhat computes one candidate position and just checks whether the word is there. Bit more complicated than that, of course, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming there are no duplicates in those lists and/or you want to de-duplicate the lists anyway, and you don't care about the order, create two sets and get the difference:

```
selectedwords = set(map(str.lower, allwords)) - set(stopwords)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the algorithm for computing set differences still simply iterates over the first list, so converting `allwords` to a `set` first isn't really going to speed things up.

Comment: Could use `set(map(str.lower, allwords))`.

Comment: @chepner That depends on the implementation I suppose. Using a native set difference method is potentially much faster when implemented in C than a Python loop would be.

Comment: `selectedwords = list(sorted( set(...) - set(...) ))` to be precise (`sorted` is optional of course).

Comment: Building the set in the first place is the issue; if you building the set solely to compute this difference, there is no net gain.

Comment: Thanks. I do need the duplicates in list allwords. Did not specify this, sorry. Still learned something from your proposal as I did not know this trick which I can use for other purposes.

Comment: @chepner Actually at least in my test (in my answer now), it's *slower*.